# How does the CACHE option of CREATE SEQUENCE work?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

`CREATE SEQUENCE` has `CACHE` option

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql) defines it as

> ```
> [ CACHE [<constant> ] | NO CACHE ]
> ```
>
> Increases performance for applications that use sequence objects by
>   minimizing the number of disk IOs that are required to generate
>   sequence numbers. Defaults to CACHE. For example, if a cache size of
>   50 is chosen, SQL Server does not keep 50 individual values cached. It
>   only caches the current value and the number of values left in the
>   cache. This means that the amount of memory required to store the
>   cache is always two instances of the data type of the sequence object.

I understand it improves performance by avoiding reads from disk IO and maintaining some info in the memory that would help reliably generate the next number in the sequence, but I cannot imagine what a simple memory representation of the cache would look like for what the MSDN describes in the example.

Can someone explain how would the cache work with this sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE s
    AS INT
    START WITH 0  
    INCREMENT BY 25  
    CACHE 5
```

describing what the cache memory would hold when each of the following statements is executed independently:

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR s -- returns 0
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR s -- returns 25
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR s -- returns 50
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR s -- returns 75
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR s -- returns 100
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR s -- returns 125
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This paragraph in the doc is very helpful:

> For an example, a new sequence is created with a starting value of 1 and a cache size of 15. When the first value is needed, values 1
>   through 15 are made available from memory. The last cached value (15)
>   is written to the system tables on the disk. When all 15 numbers are
>   used, the next request (for number 16) will cause the cache to be
>   allocated again. The new last cached value (30) will be written to the
>   system tables.

So, in your scenario

```
CREATE SEQUENCE s
    AS INT
    START WITH 0  
    INCREMENT BY 25  
    CACHE 5
```

You will have `0, 25, 50, 75 and 100` in Memory and you will get only one I/O write in disk: `100`.

The problem you could have, explained in the the doc, is if the server goes down and you haven't used all the 5 items, next time you ask for a value you'll get `125`.