# Understanding JPA sequence generator

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring data JPA's sequence generator to assign primary keys to entities.

Model contains:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_post")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_post", allocationSize = 5)
private Long id;
```

The corresponding sequence definition(for SQL Server DB):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.seq_post START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 5;
```

Since I wanted to start the ids from 100 instead of 1, so I updated the sql script to

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.seq_post START WITH 100 INCREMENT BY 5;
```

And then I encountered the problem as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34044928/hibernate-5-sequence-generate-issue/34047121). I fixed it by the solution mentioned there.

This made me wonder, when I want the DB sequence to start from 1 then why does this issue does not happen? Based on the answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34047121/13866126) I would expect the ids to not start from 1, but that does not happen. Why is that the case?

Comment: Because Hibernate is smart enough to not give negative sequence numbers. It is an edge case from this point of view, when you start from 1.

Comment: No, that's not the case. I had a situation where there were negative ids assigned as PK.

Comment: Well the `start with 1` seems to be a unique exception, for all other values the `allocationSize` is *subtracted*, so you are right, if you set the sequence to e.g. `start with 3`, you'll get the first `ID` negative  `(3-allocationSize)`

Comment: Actually `Hibernate` is *open source*, so you should be able to find the source code of the `new_generator_mappings`. You'll find there so line with `if (nextval == 1) ...  else ... subtract allocationSize`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first check if you set the property `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings` to `true` as [recomended](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier)

Than you are right in *adjusting* the `allocationSize` with the sequence `INCREMENT BY`.

If you want to *start* the `ID` with a specific value it seems to obey the following rules:

- to start with *one* set the sequence to `START WITH 1` (this seems to be an exception)
- to start with `X > 1`  set the sequence `START WITH X + 50`  (accually the same is true for `X < 1`)

e.g. to start with `5000` with the default `allocationSize` of `50` define the sequence as follows

```
create sequence sub_seq
       START WITH 5050
       INCREMENT BY 50
       NOCACHE;
```

Note that I'm using the `NOCACHE` option, because I assume Hibernate is the *only user* of this sequence, so *caching* is not realy meningfull (and actually *replaced* with the allocation size.

You also *loose* between the sessions approx. 1/2 of the `allocationSize`of the `ID`s and you do not want to increase it with additional loss of the cached `ID`s.

Comment: Could you also add this https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators to your answer, so that future readers are aware of it?

Comment: I had my application up and running and I manually reseted the DB sequence to 1 and my next id started from `1-allocationSize`, hence the confusion. Also I was not able to find the source code where this logic `if (nextval == 1) ...  else ... subtract allocationSize` is being performed. It would be great if you could share it.

Comment: Thanks, for the detailed answer. I didn't knew about the `NOCACHE` option. Other readers might also be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44988410