# Hibernate increases DB sequence by 50000

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Originally Hibernate inserted new values with ID starting from 50. But after redeployment the new IDs are 50050, 50051 etc.

Why so? How do I configure it to increment by 1 always?

DB is Oracle.

Sequence's SQL:

```
create sequence my_seq increment by 1 cache 1000;
```

Column setup:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seqGeneratorMySeq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seqGeneratorMySeq", sequenceName = "MY_SEQ")
private Long id;
```

Comment: you should check the `curval` of the sequence in the database. I think hibernate here has nothing to do. If you are redeploying, are you recreating the sequence from scratch ?

Comment: If you cache by 1000 and restart you may not get the next sequence as +1.  There is no guarantee that the next sequence will be +1 of the prior sequence. You could maybe set the cache to 1, but that is not efficient.

Comment: Check the setting of [`hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier) if it is `true`.  See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67939356/4808122) comment to the `cache` size

Comment: @MarmiteBomber but I think I had problems when the first value was true. I guess Hibernate was trying to find its own sequence and not mine in the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346147/hibernate-oracle-sequence-produces-large-gap)
In short: set up sequence params (like increment, cache size, etc) in the Entity class, not only in DB